# p4 command not found

Tags: macos, command-line, perforce

I'm trying to use p4 commands in my batch files on Mac like p4 login etc.
I keep getting the error "-bash p4: command not found".

I followed the top 7 steps here and got the same error:
http://www.endlesslycurious.com/2008/11/11/configuring-p4-command-line-client-on-mac-os-x/

I couldn't find anything else useful when searching.
Has anyone else encountered a similar issue and resolved it?

Comment: Please drop into terminal and post the results of the following: `echo  $PATH` (case matters), `which p4`, and `ls -l [the full path to where you placed the binary for p4]`.    Also, make sure that the `p4` command has execute permissions (`chmod +x [path to p4]`)

Answer (score 7):

Just drop the "p4" executable in /usr/local/bin or even /usr/bin if you prefer. ;-)

Answer (score 7):

How-To steps:

(1) Download **p4** file for **macOS** from:

https://www.perforce.com/downloads/helix-command-line-client-p4

(2) Copy the item to any local folder under any custom folder. For ex: '/Users//perforce'

(3) Run the following commands in terminal.

```
chmod +x /Users/<yourname>/perforce/p4
export PATH=/Users/<yourname>/perforce:$PATH
```

(4) Now run 'p4' in terminal.

This should not fail!

Comment: Nice to know. I had issues while integrating perforce with IntelliJ. Later, with help of your post, I figured out there was no command line perforce installed in my workstation when I installed P4V. I thought P4 command line comes bundled with P4V (looks like it is not).

Comment: @RedHunt Glad to know that this solution has worked for you. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

To add to the existing answers, on my macOS Mojave, downloading Perforce 2019.1/1796703 for OSX 10.10+ using Safari gives me a `p4.dms` file.

You must rename it to `p4` first before using it. Any attempt to unarchive the `.dms` file will fail. It is not a valid DMS archive.